# FormValidation.io won't work within UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, validation, updatepanel, formvalidation-plugin

I'm using the formvalidation.io plugin to perform client-side validation on my pages.  I've recently come across a problem where I cannot get the validation to work after a postback within an UpdatePanel (the validated controls are within the UpdatePanel as well).

Start of UP:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ActivityType" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ActivitySubType" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers> .... </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The validation works as intended until a postback occurs.  Each time ActivityType or ActivitySubType perform a postback, all validation disappears.

Javascript / jQuery:

```
 $(function () {
        docReady(); 
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () { docReady(); });

    function docReady() {
        $("#aspnetForm").formValidation({
            message: 'This value is not valid',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {

                ctl00$maincontent$ActivityDate:
                        {
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: 'Date / Time is required'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                ...
            }
        }); } });
```

I've tried doing the validation declaratively as well with the same result.  I've also tried re-initializing the validation using the console after postback with no luck.

I'm a bit frustrated b/c I've tried everything I know to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. As you've seen the validation can work initially, but after a postback, it stops working. I tried using the javascript pageLoad() function which gets called by the asp framework after a postback is completed.

I have found that setting the formValidation to null each after each postback seems to resolve the problem.  See my code below.  I call the isFormValid() function from my asp submit button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function isFormValid() {
        var formValidation = $('form').data('formValidation');
        formValidation.validate();
        if (formValidation.isValid() != true) {
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // called by Ajax Framework after postback
    function pageLoad() {
        setupValidation();
    }

    function setupValidation() {
         $('form').data('formValidation',null);
         $('form').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

In your case - try the following:

```
$("#aspnetForm").data('formValidation',null);
$("#aspnetForm").formValidation({....
```